# Acronyms with Full stops python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, acronym

I have code which reads a text file and outputs the amount of TLA's in the text as a percentage out of how many lines contain text.

```
import re
total_lines = 0
matched_lines = 0
for line in open("sentences.txt"):
    total_lines += 1
    matched_lines += bool(re.search(r"\b[A-Z]{3}\b", line))
    matched_lines += bool(re.search(r"\b[A-Z]\\.[A-Z]\\.[A-Z]\b", line)) # DOES NOT WORK
print('{}% of sentences contain a TLA'.format(round(float(matched_lines) / total_lines * 100, 1)))
```

What i'm trying to do is count TLA's with full stops between them. So like now it counts WWW but i want it to count W.W.W as well.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer on your previous question that supplied you with this code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your re it should be `\.` not `\\.`.

In Python an `r` outside a string makes a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/208880).  The benefit of raw string literals is that backslashes (`\`) are not special to Python, which means it's easier to pass through to `re` where they are special.

In both lines you are using raw string literals (good!), so the `\b` is specifying a word boundary.  However, the `\\.` is looking for a `\` followed by any character.  What you want is `\.` which is a literal `.`.